# Change plugin main file name (that is currently in the repo)

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Thought I'd ask before I give it a shot and break my plugin.

Is it possible to update a plugin's main file name that IS CURRENTLY in the repo?

It was the first plugin I ever made, and the file name is SUPER long...

Thanks!

Comment: Best guess is reaching out to the contributors @ plugins at wordpress dot org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually mean a main *file* (the one with header data) inside the plugin you can rename it freely. I think the only thing would happen is that it will deactivate on update and will need to be activated again by user.

But if you mean plugin slug in the repository (the one in URL) — those are fixed in stone (or at least SVN) and cannot be changed.

Comment: Perhaps I'm using the wrong terminology. I mean the zip file someone would download. I'm going to try changing it and upload it via SVN sometime tomorrow. Any thoughts would be helpful!

Comment: Download is likely based on repository slug and thus also unchangeable.